# php change textbox value base on drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table name tbl_material:

> material | description
>
> 1000    |   Samsung
>
> 2000    |  Iphone

i write the code below to get material field into drop down list of HTML

```
require ("con_config.php");
$select_material_code = "SELECT material, description FROM tbl_material";
$get_material_code = mysqli_query ($con, $select_material_code);
$options_material_Code = "--Select Product--";
$option_material_description = "";
while ($result_material_code = mysqli_fetch_array($get_material_code))
{
    $options_material_Code = $options_material_Code."<option>$result_material_code[1]</option>";
}
```

Here is HTML

```
<select name="materialcode_1" id="materialcode_1">
<option value = "<?php echo $options_material_Code;?>"><?php echo $options_material_Code;?></option>
</select>
```

I have a textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="description_1" placeholder="Description" maxlength="40" size="40" value="" id="description_1">
```

I want to get description field from tbl_material if i change drop down list value. how to do it? please help....

Comment: Question not very clear..add more description to question..

Comment: In drop down list has "material" field already which retrieve from tbl_material, therefore, i want to fetch textbox value from "description" field in tbl_material if i change drop down list. please let me know if you need more info. "material" field has data: 1000, 2000 and "description" field has data: Samsung, Iphone. if i select 1000 of drop down list, then textbox value will fetch Samsung.

Comment: include the description in the drop down like `<option data-description = " <?php echo $description;?> " value = "<?php echo $options_material_Code;?>"><?php echo $options_material_Code;?></option>` work this out in the php page...then on change event of dropdwon get the data-description and apply it on the textbox..

Comment: let me know if you have any question on the solution given above

Comment: what's change event of dropdown? could you show me?

Comment: @guradio - should probably use `htmlentities()` if you're going to do it like that.

Comment: say you have created the data-attribute and it has values check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6a344Lr6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#materialcode_1").change(function(e) {
    $("#description_1").val($("#materialcode_1").val())

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes the description may contain arbitrary text, possibly text longer than you'd want to put in the value of the dropdown, that's why I used a JSON object.

First, let's just get all the results at once so we can JSON encode them, and then do our looping.

```
$result_material_code = mysqli_fetch_all($get_material_code, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<select name="materialcode_1" id="materialcode_1">';
foreach($result_material_code as $index=>$row){
    echo "<option value='$index'>{$row['material']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Then we drop the JSON into a Javascript and use jQuery to listen for changes to the drop-down. When the user changes the drop down, show an alert with the description.

```
$(function(){
    // Give the DB results to JavaScript
    var materialcode_1_data = <?php echo json_encode($result_material_code); ?>;

    // Listen for Dropdown changes
    $("#materialcode_1").change(function(){
        // Alert the description
        alert(materialcode_1_data[$(this).val()].description);
    });
});
```

See:

[mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

[change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#materialcode_1').on('change', function() {
  $('#description_1').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, any problem with PHP? cause $option_material_description = ""; is empty

Comment: You set `value = "<?php echo $options_material_Code;?>"`  change this to description. It will work.
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gc3n9zwn/)